# Polynomial irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, integers

Let $f(x) = x^4 + x^2 + x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$

Show that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$, then factor $f$ over $K = \frac{\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]}{(f(x))}$ 

I first tried to use Eisenstein criterion to prove the irreducibility but since we are working over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$, neither $f(x)$, $f(x+1)$ nor $f(x+2)$ satisfies the Eisenstein criterion and i can't find another way to prove this irreducibility.

Any help would be truly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion cannot apply. Its scope is restricted to coefficient fields that are fields of fractions of a suitable integral domain. Here that is  impossible. Another way to look at it is to notice that in a field there are no primes/irreducible elements, because anything non-zero is a unit.

Comment: What do you know about possible factorizations/ possible factors of $f(x)$? For example about their degrees. Do you know how to eliminate some (all?) relevant possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the quickest way but a method nonetheless:

If it was to be reducible, it must either have a linear factor or a quadratic factor.

A quick check shows it cannot be linear so it has to be $$f(x) = P1(x)P2(x)$$
where both $P1$ and $P2$ are irreducible quadratics.

Also note that it has to be the case that either both $P1(x)$ and $P2(x)$ have leading coefficient of $1$ or both have the leading coefficient $2$.

Now a quick search shows there are $3$ irreducible quadratics with leading coeff $1$ and similarly for leading coeff $2$. So just by checking $6$ possibilities should give you the irreducibility.

Comment: Small note that the leading coefficient doesn't really matter as long as it is a unit anyway